# How to keep Paging Bar from jumping to the top of the right column?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, pagination, asp.net-mvc-5

This may be a simple fix and I have searched for an answer already and did not find one. My paging bar jumps to the top when there are just a few pages present as seen below:

[image]

How do i keep it from jumping to the top right when there are just a few pages?

The Partial View:

```
div class="container">
<div class="col-md-8">

    <div class="posts">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="content">
            <h2>Archive from @DateAndTime.MonthName(ViewContext.RouteData.Values("Month")) @ViewContext.RouteData.Values("Year")</h2>
               @For Each item In Model.ToList
                 @<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-default panel-body">
                       @item.PostDateCreated.Value.ToShortDateString @item.PostDateCreated.Value.AddHours(3).ToShortTimeString
                         <div class="galleryImgWrapper">
                           <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Posts", New With {.id = item.Id, .title = (item.PostTitle).ToSeoUrl}, Nothing)">
                            @Html.Raw(item.PostSummary.GetImage)
                            </a>
                            </div>
                            <h4>@Html.ActionLink(item.PostTitle, "Details", "Posts", New With {.id = item.Id, .title = item.PostTitle.ToSeoUrl}, Nothing)</h4>
                            @Html.Raw(item.PostSummary.RemoveImgWithRegex)
                    </div>
                 </div>
             Next
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>



    @Html.BootstrapPager(ViewContext.RouteData.Values("Page"),
      Function(index) Url.Action("Archives", "Posts", New With {.page = index}), 
      ViewBag.count, System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.
      AppSettings("PageSize"), 20)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it - added a really wide width for the paging bar and that keeps it all on line and from jumping to the top.

```
.superwide {
width:100000px;
}
```